# How to use useState while using redux to set initial value?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I understand it's not good practise.

```
      const UserList = () => { 
          const useArray =   useSelector(state =>  state.users.users)

          const [listItems, setListItems] = useState(Array.from(useArray.slice(0, 30)))


          listItems.map(listItem =>  console.log(listItem) )

        };
```

I set the initial state, but when I map it I get nothing.

Comment: Connect the component and put your selector in `mapStateToProps`

Comment: isn't useSelector an alternative to mapStateToProps?

Comment: You're expected to use `useSelector` in `mapStateToProps` so you don't pass the entire state chunk to your component, since it only needs a tiny slice. Only pass to a component what it needs to render.